# Power Bi embed report to web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a power bi report which i am embedding on my web application.

Is there is anyway that is can embed directly a drill down view of the report?

in short i want to open the report in drill down mode on.How can i do this programmatically.

I am using dot net mvc for my web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible (assuming that you want to apply a "default" filter in your report). When you embed the report, you can add a list of `filters` to your `embedConfig` ([documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details)):

```
var embedConfig = {
  ...
  filters: [...]
};
```

A single filter, in the list of filters, can look like the following ([documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters)):

```
const myFilter = {
            $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
            target: {
                table: "Table1",
                column: "Column1"
            },
            operator: "In",
            values: ["A"]
        };
```

In which case you specify the `filters` in `embedConfig` according to

```
filters: [myFilter]
```

However, note that this is not a secure way to prevent users from seeing data, a user can easily, using javascript, remove the filter and gain access to all the data.